# pyspark read form s3 and write to elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm trying to read from s3 and write to Elasticsearch, 
using jupyter install on spark master machine

I have this configuration:

```
import pyspark
import os
#os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell"
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/credentials"))
aws_profile='DEFAULT'
access_id = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_access_key_id") 
access_key = config.get(aws_profile, "aws_secret_access_key")

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc_conf = SparkConf()
sc_conf.setAppName("app-3-logstash")
sc_conf.setMaster('spark://172.31.25.152:7077')
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.memory', '24g')
sc_conf.set('spark.executor.cores', '8')
sc_conf.set('spark.cores.max', '32')
sc_conf.set('spark.logConf', True)
sc_conf.set('spark.packages', 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3')
sc_conf.set('spark.jars', '/usr/local/spark/jars/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.6.0/dist/elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11-7.6.0.jar')
sc = SparkContext(conf=sc_conf)

hadoop_conf=sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", access_id)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", access_key)
```

using this configuration, I get access to ES and not S3
when try to read from s3 using this conf I get this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found

When disabling sc_conf.set('spark.packages'.. and sc_conf.set('spark.jars', .. and enable #os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] , it do get access to s3 but not to ES

What do I miss?

Thanks
Yaniv